# after editing logrotate file do I need to restart something?

Tags: debian, logrotate

After editing /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog do I need to restart some service before it takes effect?

Comment: No. `logrotate` is run periodically, and will notice your changes the next time it runs. You should run it manually to test your changes.

Answer (score 1):

There’s nothing to do, `logrotate` is run as a cron job (once a day, by default) and will take your configuration changes into account the next time it runs.

As mentioned by [waltinator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/11135/waltinator), you can run `logrotate` manually yourself to check that your changes work as expected (but this will cause an early rotation of all your logs).